# Creating a fixed size circle view in android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-view

So I have a bit of a frustrating one for me. What I would like to achieve is essentially a button that has two textviews in the center of it. One with a name and one with a number value to it... Like a counter...

I would like it to look like this:

[image: Counter Idea]

There is a thin white border around it (which given it's colour isn't exactly visible... sorry).

What I'd like to do is have the value increment and decrement depending on how the button is pressed.

Now I have the following so far:

attrs.xml

```
<resources>
<declare-styleable name="ButtonCounter">
    <attr name="backgroundColor" format="color"/>
    <attr name="borderColor" format="color"/>
    <attr name="borderSize" format="integer"/>
    <attr name="labelNameColor" format="color"/>
    <attr name="labelValueColor" format="color"/>
    <attr name="labelName" format="string"></attr>
    <attr name="labelValue" format="string"></attr>
</declare-styleable>
```

ButtonCounter.java

```
public class ButtonCounter extends View {
private int                 backgroundColor,
                            borderColor,
                            borderSize,
                            labelNameColor,
                            labelValueColor;
private String              labelName,
                            labelValue;
private Paint               paintCircle,
                            paintStroke;

public ButtonCounter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);

    paintCircle = new Paint();
    paintStroke = new Paint();

    TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            attrs,
            R.styleable.ButtonCounter
            ,
            0,
            0
    );

    try {
        backgroundColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ButtonCounter_backgroundColor, 0);
        borderColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ButtonCounter_borderColor, 0);
        borderSize = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ButtonCounter_borderSize, 0);
        labelNameColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ButtonCounter_labelNameColor,0);
        labelValueColor = a.getInteger(R.styleable.ButtonCounter_labelValueColor, 0 );
        labelName = a.getString(R.styleable.ButtonCounter_labelName);
        labelValue = a.getString(R.styleable.ButtonCounter_labelValue);
    } finally {
        a.recycle();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paintCircle.setColor(backgroundColor);
    paintCircle.setAntiAlias(true);
    paintStroke.setColor(borderColor);
    paintStroke.setAntiAlias(true);

    int width = this.getMeasuredWidth();
    int height = this.getMeasuredHeight();

    int diameter = ((height > width) ? height : width);
    int radius = diameter / 2;


    canvas.drawCircle(diameter / 2, diameter / 2, radius - borderSize, paintCircle);
    canvas.drawCircle(diameter / 2, diameter / 2, radius, paintStroke);
}
```

}

This doesn't do what I want it to already as it becomes way too big.

Any ideas on how I could start attempting this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it in easy way ? Creating a `ShapeDrawable` xml ?

Comment: try using drawable

Comment: How do you use your view in your layout?

Answer (score 0):

Hi If you want to achieve the same without using Java Class then see the below solution:

1. Create a drawable with any name lets circle_bg_xml

> ```
>  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>         android:shape="oval">
>         <solid android:color="@color/black" />
>     </shape>
> ```

2. Now in your layout use put two TextViews(or any view) inside LinearLayout and set that drawable as Layout background.

> ```
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="100dp"
>     android:layout_height="100dp"
>     android:gravity="center"
>     android:background="@drawable/circle_bg">
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:textColor="@color/white"
>         android:textSize="15sp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="Global"/>
>     <TextView
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:textColor="@color/white"
>         android:textSize="22sp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:text="0"/>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

Hope it will help you. 
Thanks

Comment: Am I able to add all that dynamically within the Java code instead? Sorry, I wrote the question at 3 am and was half asleep so forgot to mention that I need to be able to add more than one when the user needs the counters